# Why is the recursion idiom in Haskell "'n+1' and 'n'" and not "'n' and 'n-1'"?

Tags: haskell, recursion, idioms

I'm working my way through Graham Hutton's Haskell book, and in his recursion chapter, he often pattern-matches on "n+1", as in:

```
myReplicate1 0 _ = []
myReplicate1 (n+1) x = x : myReplicate1 n x
```

Why that and not the following, which (1) seems functionally identical and (2) more intuitive in terms of understanding what's happening with the recursion:

```
myReplicate2 0 _ = []
myReplicate2 n x = x : myReplicate2 (n-1) x
```

Is there something I'm missing here? Or is it just a matter of style?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are n+k patterns (that should be avoided!) in the first function. Both functions do the same thing, **except for the n+k one not matching negative numbers.** The latter one, however, is recommended, **and can be adopted if you want no negative numbers on purpose**, because the n+k patterns are sheduled to be [removed anyways](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/RemoveNPlusK).

So no, you're missing nothing, and it is indeed a matter of style, but I rarely see n+k patterns in the wild.

Comment: In other words, it's a matter of style, and the first style is deprecated. :)

Comment: They're not the same actually. n+k patterns will not match negative numbers.

Comment: Whoops, didn't consider that! Thanks, sepp, I edited my answer!

Comment: Very interesting - and I guess I WAS missing something (the n >= 0 bit). It's kind of strange magical behavior. I think it's funny that one of the arguments against removing it is that "some Haskell books use it" :)

Answer (score 6):

I think the idea behind it is this: We can define a type for the natural numbers (0, 1, ...) like this:

```
data Natural = Z -- zero
             | S Natural -- one plus a number; the next number; the "successor"
```

`0 = Z`, `1 = S Z`, and so on. This system is called Peano arithmetic, and is pretty much a standard in mathematics as a (starting point for a) definition of what a "number" actually is. You can go on to define `Integer`s as pairs(-ish) of `Natural`s, and so on.

When you do this, it becomes natural to use pattern matching like this:

```
myReplicate1 Z _ = []
myReplicate1 (S n) x = x : myReplicate1 n x
```

I think (and it's just a guess) that the idea behind `n+1` patterns is a machine version of what I just described. So, `n+1` is to be thought of like the pattern `S n`. If you're thinking this way, `n+1` patterns seem natural. This also makes it clear why we have the side condition that `n >= 0`. We can only represent `n >= 0` using the type `Natural`.

Answer (score 3):

N+K patterns also have different strictness implications.

For example:

```
f (n+1) = Just n
g n = Just (n-1)
```

f is strict on its first argument, g is not. This is nothing special with n+k patterns but applies to all patterns.

Answer (score 2):

n+k patterns only match when n>=0. So in your myReplicate1 the n+1 pattern will match only positive numbers and a negative n will cause a nonexhaustive-pattern exception. In myReplicate2 a negative n would create an infinite list.

So in other words you can use n+k patterns when you don't want the pattern to match negative numbers, but using a guard instead will be clearer.

Answer (score -4):

```
myReplicate n x = take n (repeat x)
```

Done and done. :D